# MongoDB hide key when querying in Eloquent

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent

When I perform a query using `whereIn` like this:

```
$data = User::whereIn('name', $sample)->select('numbers')->get();
```

I get results like:

```
[{"numbers":["100","101"]},{"numbers":["100","101","103"]}, ...]
```

I would like to know if it possible to hide the *"numbers"* keys, note that this is not a projection since *"numbers"* is part of the searched information. The result should look like:

```
["100","101","100","101","103", ...]
```

Allowing me to perform operations on several thousands results.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **[`raw()`](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#raw-expressions)** method in this case and use the native MongoCollection methods like **[`aggregate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)** to group the documents and push the numbers key values to an array that you can then iterate over with your cursor, something like this (untested):

```
$data = DB::collection('users')->raw(function($collection)
{
    $cursor = $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            '$match' => array('name' => $sample)
        ),
        array(
            '$unwind' => '$numbers'
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => null,
                'numbers' => array(
                    '$push' => '$numbers'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                '_id' => 0,
                'numbers' => 1
            )
        )       
    ));

    $elems = array();
    // Iterate cursor
    $current = $cursor;
    do {
        $elems[] = $current->$numbers;
    } while (!($current = $cursor->next()));

    return array_values($elems);    
});
```